# AndroidJUnit test does not find design support snackbar on API level 17 device

Tags: android, android-espresso, androiddesignsupport, android-junit

I have an AndroidJUnit4 testcase, within this test case I'm using the following code to verify that the snackbar is displayed and contains the right text:

```
onView(withId(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onView(allOf(withId(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text), withText(R.string.msg_error_unknown_user)))
                    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

When I run this test on an emulator/device with API level 22, the tests run correct. When I switch to API level 17, the test fails with this exception:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.mydomain.myappname:id/snackbar_text
```

Note that the application behaves in the same way on both API level; the snackbar is being displayed correctly.

Why is in my testcase the snackbar not retrieved on API level 17 and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Espresso` is looking into your your `xml` file and searching for `snackbar_text`, but it won't find it as it has android system id, where `Espresso`don't have access. If you still want to check it, please learn about another Google instrumentation testing framework called `uiautomator`.

Here you would find how it work along with `Espresso`: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

Also please take your time to see how I've already tested `Snackbar` in a code below:

```
@Test
public void checkIfSnackBarIsProperlyDisplayed() throws InterruptedException {
        onView(withId(R.id.fab)).perform(click());
        onView(withText(R.string.function_not_available)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    }

    @Test
    public void clickOnFloatingActionButtonToShowSnackBar() {
        onView(withId(R.id.fab)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.snackbar_text))
                .check(matches(withText(R.string.function_not_available)));

    }

    @Test
    public void swipeRightToDismissDisplayedCommunique() {
        onView(withId(R.id.fab)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.snackbar_text))
                .perform(swipeRight())
                .check(matches(not(isCompletelyDisplayed())));

    }
}
```

Hope you find it useful.